# Trying to start new laravel project, get '451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons'

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I've recently started studying laravel and found out that I'm unable to create new laravel project in vagrant, using *laravel new* command:

[451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWNjf.png)

It turns out that here, in Russia, [cabinet.laravel.com](http://cabinet.laravel.com) is in the list of **forbidden** sites and response is actually correct.

If anyone faced the same problem and found out how to solve it, I'd be happy to see the decisions.

Here's what I tried:

1. Turn on the Tor32 service (I'm on Windows 10). Unfortunately I kept getting permission errors.
2. Use Proxy. I was able to open url using browser (which wasn't really a problem), but terminal kept throwing the same error.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10. I typed it in the list.

Comment: I was blind sorry, was about to suggest to use curl with proxy when you are using terminal, but u fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `laravel new` command. Instead you can use `composer create-project laravel/laravel <project-name>`. You would then replace `<project-name>` with the name of your project. For example:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel myapp`

Comment: Well, I managed to create a project which was my problem in first place, so thank you very much. Still don't know how to solve 451, tho. I just hope there will be no need in that)

Comment: No problem, it's probably not worth the effort to try and get around the 451 response